# Angular: Best way the show the correct page over overview page

Tags: angular, pagination

I have an overview page seperated by a pager(see image):

[image]

When I click on an item in the overview I get routed to a new page.
What is the best practice for saving on which page you were in the overview.

Is this by button the page in the link? or by a getters and setters?

Does someone have some advice

THX a lot!

Comment: you can use ngrx which implement redux in angular having your store saving the "current" page, or you can also use browser's localstorage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no best way, depends on what is viable for you.

One way will be to make it a part of url using [appropriate url paramater](https://angular.io/guide/router). This way, the state is managed by router itself and goes well with the idea of state preserved in URL. You can send URLs around with deep routing to the level of a page. Easy to maintain and debug. Easily goes well with browser back button as well. Downside is an extra param in url making it *ugly*

Another way is to persist the table state in local/session storage. This is essentially caching and will bring all the complexities of caching and cache invalidation. Also, the state of the app comes partially from router and partially from state stored in persistent storage. Some components for data supports emitting a state and persisting the same in session/local by setting a flag, you can explore those and use one of them as well. When it comes to multiple tables in same page or across different pages you have to be careful in managing unique states for each.

Another way would be using redux to manage state, you may have to use ngrx/store for the same. Not sure how well it integrates with URL and browser navigation. Also if you are not using redux already this can be a steep learning curve and using a powerful state management library for a simple task. IF you go with redux, it will be better to use it across the app.

Comment: THX a Lot this really helps